# Animate UIView to fold one half onto the other half

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, calayer, caanimation

I have the following problem.
I want to write a method with which i can fold one half of a UIView onto the other half.

The algorithm is clear to me (at least i think so, but maybe i forgot something).

1. Create a rendered image of the UIView
2. split it depending on which half i want to fold onto the other
3. add the corresponding halfs of the rendered image to the corresponding layers
4. add the two layers to a backgroundlayer with white background and no contents (it is just there to make a white background to cover up the original layer of the view)
5. add the backgroundlayer to the views layer
6. set the transform for the folding layer
7. start the animation

Should work, but doesn't! And I have no idea why. :(

Here is the sourcecode of the Method:

```
-(void)foldView:(UIView *) view withDuration: (NSTimeInterval) duration toSide: (NSString*) side withReverse: (bool) reverse andRepeatCount:(float) repeatCount
{
    //create Screenshot from view to fold
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img_view = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Bildausschnitte festlegen
    CGRect rect_closingImageHalf = view.bounds;    
    CGRect rect_fixedImageHalf = view.bounds;    

    CGPoint pt_anchorOpeningImageHalf;
    CGPoint pt_anchorFixedImageHalf;

    CATransform3D transform;

    CALayer *lay_closingImageHalf;
    CALayer *lay_fixedImageHalf;
    lay_fixedImageHalf.masksToBounds = YES;
    lay_closingImageHalf.masksToBounds = YES;
    //get white backside of layer which folds
    lay_closingImageHalf.doubleSided = NO;


    //white backgroundlayer to hide the layer of the image
    CALayer *backgroundAnimationLayer = [CALayer layer];
    backgroundAnimationLayer.frame = view.frame;
    backgroundAnimationLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

    //determine direction in which to fold    
    if ([side isEqualToString:k_side_vonLinks]) 
    {
        rect_closingImageHalf = CGRectMake(0, 0, img_view.size.width / 2, img_view.size.height);
        rect_fixedImageHalf = CGRectMake(img_view.size.width / 2, 0, img_view.size.width / 2, img_view.size.height);

        pt_anchorOpeningImageHalf = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);        
        pt_anchorFixedImageHalf = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1.0, 0);
    }
    else if([side isEqualToString:k_side_vonRechts])
    {
        rect_closingImageHalf = CGRectMake(img_view.size.width / 2, 0, img_view.size.width / 2, img_view.size.height);
        rect_fixedImageHalf = CGRectMake(0, 0, img_view.size.width / 2, img_view.size.height);

        pt_anchorOpeningImageHalf = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
        pt_anchorFixedImageHalf = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);   

        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1.0, 0);
    }
    else if([side isEqualToString:k_side_vonOben])
    {
        rect_closingImageHalf = CGRectMake(0, 0, img_view.size.width, img_view.size.height / 2);
        rect_fixedImageHalf = CGRectMake(0, img_view.size.height / 2, img_view.size.width, img_view.size.height / 2);

        pt_anchorOpeningImageHalf = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
        pt_anchorFixedImageHalf = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0, 0, 0);
    }
    else if([side isEqualToString:k_side_vonUnten])
    {
        rect_closingImageHalf = CGRectMake(0, img_view.size.height / 2, img_view.size.width, img_view.size.height / 2);
        rect_fixedImageHalf = CGRectMake(0, 0, img_view.size.width, img_view.size.height / 2);

        pt_anchorOpeningImageHalf = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
        pt_anchorFixedImageHalf = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0, 0, 0);
    }

    CGImageRef img_closingHalf = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( [img_view CGImage], rect_closingImageHalf);
    CGImageRef img_fixedHalf = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( [img_view CGImage], rect_fixedImageHalf);    

    lay_closingImageHalf.anchorPoint = pt_anchorOpeningImageHalf;
    lay_fixedImageHalf.anchorPoint = pt_anchorFixedImageHalf;


    //add the rendered image of the view to the backgroundLayer
    [backgroundAnimationLayer addSublayer:lay_fixedImageHalf];
    [backgroundAnimationLayer addSublayer:lay_closingImageHalf];
    lay_closingImageHalf.contents = (__bridge id)img_closingHalf;
    lay_fixedImageHalf.contents = (__bridge id)img_fixedHalf;


    [view.layer addSublayer:backgroundAnimationLayer];

    //add perspective
    transform.m34 = 1.0f / 2500.0f;

    //animate the folding of the layer
    CABasicAnimation *flipAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    flipAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
    flipAnimation.duration = duration;
    flipAnimation.autoreverses = reverse;
    flipAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount;
    flipAnimation.delegate = self;
    flipAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    flipAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    [backgroundAnimationLayer addAnimation:flipAnimation forKey:@"fold"];
}
```

If someone of you has an idea why it doesn't work i would be very glad if he can help.
I googled almost a day and read many samples but i cannot find the mistake.
I also looked into [AFKPageFLipper](https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper) which is a really great example for this task, but unfortunately it didn't help me to find out whats wrong with my code.

Hope that someone can help me.

Comment: Doesn't work means "draws nothing" or "doesn't animate correctly" or "crashes" or ???

Comment: doesn't work means in this case, that the Backgroundlayer seems to be invisible (thus rendering the sublayers invisible too, at least i cant see them). So if the Layer to be animated is not visible i cannot see the animation.
Why it's invisile though i do not know. 
But you should be able to test this method in any project:
The last time i tested it with adding the layer of the view to the animation. This at least produced a visible animation, although it was of course not the desired one.

Comment: Nobody an idea?
Maybe i should start a bounty on this one. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at these two projects that include the effect you are trying to create:

https://github.com/blommegard/SBTickerView

https://github.com/raweng/FlipView

Comment: FlipView uses AFKPageFlipper which i tried already. I'll look into SBTickerView though, because it looks promising from the functionality i want. It's a little closer to what i need than AFKPageFlipper.

Comment: Thx. SBTickerView is exactly what i needed. It lacks the functionality from AFKPageFlipper, but this can be integrated very easy.
Also SBTickerView was much easier to integrate. So you have earned your bounty. :)

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution :) As an additional tip - when looking for this stuff, always check out cocoacontrols.com and github.com - there are so many useful open source projects out there, but many of them aren't easy to find with Google.

Comment: thx again. I frequently check github for new stuff, but this sbTickerView i must have missed. :)

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
CALayer *lay_closingImageHalf = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *lay_fixedImageHalf = [CALayer layer];
```

instead of

```
CALayer *lay_closingImageHalf;
CALayer *lay_fixedImageHalf;
```

at least.

Also you need to set frames of `lay_closingImageHalf` and `lay_fixedImageHalf`

```
[lay_closingImageHalf setFrame:rect_closingImageHalf];
[lay_fixedImageHalf setFrame:rect_fixedImageHalf];
```

and still its flip animation not fold... Are you sure its your code?

Comment: Its partyly my code and partly code from afkpageflipper project on github. But the effect i want is not a flip per se, but a fold of one half of the layer on to the other just as you close an open book.

As to your comments both of them are correct. I don't know how i could have overlooked this. I'll fix it and give response then. :)

Comment: ok, now it at least animates something. Not what i want but at least i can dig into it a little deeper. thx!
If i know more I'll let you know.

Comment: btw, whats the difference between flip and fold in your opinion?
I always thought flip as a complete turn of the whole view and fold as a fold in the middle of the view where one half covers the other after fold is finished.